# Show that there exists a function such that all points $P_i \in k^2$ are mapped to some $\lambda_i \in k$

Tags: functions, algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, curves, projective-space

To be precise, the question is :
Let $k$ be a finite field. Let $P_{1}, \ldots, P_{m} \in k^{2}$ be distinct points and let $\lambda_1, \ldots \ldots, \lambda_{m} \in k$; show that there exists $f \in k[x, y]$ such that for all $i$ we have $f\left(P_{i}\right)=\lambda_{i}$.

at first glance this looked like showing an equivalence relation over a projective space, however the method desired seems to be different as it gives the following hint:

for a given $P=(a, b) \in k^{2}$ consider first the following polynomial: $f_{a, b}:= \prod_{v \in k, v \neq a}(X - v)$ * $ \prod_{w \in k, w \neq b}(Y - w)$ . Where is $f$ equal to $0$ and where it is not equal to $0$ ?

im not sure how to use this hint to solve the question? the $f$ given is non zero for $(a,b)$ and zero everywhere else but im not quite sure how that helps. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

thanks

Comment: Hint: If you can find a polynomial such that $f_i(P_i) = 1, f_i(P_j) = 0$, we can then take $f = \sum \lambda_i f_i $ and be done. The given hint is (close to) such a polynomial (which is why they ask when is it zero or non-zero). What do we need to tweak?

Comment: Hint for using MSE: readers care about presentation here. You will notice a better response if you take more time to present your post well: please use mathjax (including in the title), please capitalize the first letter in your sentences, please use appropriate punctuation, etc.